# Зависимость родительского окна от дочернего

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать родительское окно не зависимо от дочернего
Чтобы при закрытии дочернего родительское не закрывалось

```
// Win32Project8.cpp: определяет точку входа для приложения.
//
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project8.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst, hInst1;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WIN32PROJECT8, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT8));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WIN32PROJECT8));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WIN32PROJECT8);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: сохраняет обработку экземпляра и создает главное окно.
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В данной функции дескриптор экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится на экран главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить дескриптор экземпляра в глобальной переменной
   hInst1 = hInstance; // Сохранить дескриптор экземпляра в глобальной переменной
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, L"MYOKNO", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      10, 100, 500, 500, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   HWND hWnd1 = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, L"MYOKNO2", WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
       10, 100, 400, 400, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);


   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   ShowWindow(hWnd1, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd1);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ:  обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND — обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT — отрисовать главное окно
//  WM_DESTROY — отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере оба окна используют один и тот же оконный класс и одну и ту же оконную процедуру `WndProc`. При нажатии на кнопку `X` дочернего окна генерируется сообщение `WM_CLOSE`, которое обрабатывается дефолтной оконной процедурой, которая вызывает `DestroyWindow` для дочернего окна, которая генерирует сообщение `WM_DESTROY`, которое обрабатывается в вашей оконной процедуре посредством вызова `PostQuitMessage(0);`, который прерывает цикл `GetMessage`. При этом главное окно вообще-то не разрушается, более того, вы не сохраняете его дескриптор и поэтому не можете его разрушить. Чтобы избежать этих безобразий следует либо назначить окнам две оконных процедуры, либо по-разному обрабатывать `WM_DESTROY` для родительского и дочернего окон.